# insertExisting object instead of insertNewObjectForEntityForName

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'd like to know if there's a way to directly insert an existing NSManagedObject into Core Data instead of creating a new one and filling its instance variables.

**Edit:**
removing from the ManagedObjectContext won't work for me because I can't handle it when user presses the back button on the Navigation Bar. That's why I don't wanna insert it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of going beside the Core Data patterns, but it's possible. 
The code is smth like:

```
[yourObjectContext insertObject:unassociatedObjet];
NSError *error = nil;
[yourObjectContext save:&error];
//Check the error!
```

Perhaps, [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256195/how-to-deal-with-temporary-nsmanagedobject-instances/3258470#3258470) will be useful in your case also.

Comment: Thank you! the link guided me to find the solution. Other important step is to insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil Here's what I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256195/how-to-deal-with-temporary-nsmanagedobject-instances/6857026#6857026