# Use a subclass of Core Data Entity without storing in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an entity called "Color" that has R,G,B stored, and a subclass that returns saturation, UIColor, etc., as needed. I recently wrote some code where I needed the Color entity to be the Class "Color" so I could call a method on it.

But it seems that broke another part.

Before I store the colors, I use the Color class to figure out what colors to store, based on the methods in the Color class. This is where I'm running into problems.

```
Color *color = [[Color alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
if (color.saturation > 0.2) {
    [self addOrIncrementColor:color];
}
```

At the if statement, the debugger shows:

```
color   Color * 0x1f532740
NSManagedObject NSManagedObject 
red CGFloat 0.392157
green   CGFloat 0.443137
blue    CGFloat 0.203922
count   __NSCFNumber *  0x1f559d00
color   UIDeviceRGBColor *  0x200e8f10
saturation  CGFloat 0.539823
```

However, if I print the description of the Color object, I get:

```
Color: 0x1f532740 (entity: (null); id: (null) ; data: {})
```

This of course, passes the color object to the addOrIncrement: method with null info, even though it is set locally.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look normal to be using `NSManagedObject`s like you would for normal objects (e.g. with the usual `alloc init`. Instead, `NSManagedObject`s should be created with the `NSManagedObjectContext`.

That being said, if you just want a temporary `NSManagedObject` that will not be saved to a `context`, then create them as you would normally, but with a nil `context`:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Color" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
Color *color = [[Color alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
if (color.saturation > 0.2) {
    ...
}
```

Check out [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256195/how-to-deal-with-temporary-nsmanagedobject-instances) for reference.