# Create temporary CoreData entities (in a non-persistent MagicalRecord context)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

I simply want to create entities **yet not to be saved**, only inspect them.

Can I create a temporary context for those?
Is there a way to **move them into the persistent context** once I decided to store them?

And the point: are these features available trough [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) API?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256195/how-to-deal-with-temporary-nsmanagedobject-instances

Comment: @AlexeiKuznetsov Edited the question to be more MagicalRecord specific.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a new **NSManagedContext** that has *parentContext* property set to your main context, and create new objects in the new context - you can do everything you want with those objects, then later either *save* the new context (this will move the objects to the main context) or just discard it - the objects will be gone.

Seems that there stands an [+(NSManagedObjectContext*)MR_contextWithParent:](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/develop/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObjectContext/NSManagedObjectContext%2BMagicalRecord.h#L17) for that in MagicalRecord.

Comment: Thanks, so the point is parentContext. Gonna scan MagicalRecord docs for that.

Comment: Be warned, there are issues with parent/child contexts that you may bump into.  See e.g. http://wbyoung.tumblr.com/post/27851725562/core-data-growing-pains

Comment: @Simon the blog post is rather old, and I use nested contexts extensively, hadn't noticed those problems...

Comment: @Peter I think that whether you notice them or not depends a lot on your setup.  I still run into them, so I thought they were worth mentioning.

Comment: Which context do you use as the parent context in this case?  The default context?  The root context?  Also you mention issues w/ parent child MOC's, still the case?  Possibly better to just put temp data (not yet to be saved) in regular variables (not an entity) and only create and save the entity if the user hits save?